# Why do we use the complex electric field vector's square to define in following parameters, instand of using a single one to describe it?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, electric-fields, polarization, singularities

[image]

As the picture showed (coming from an article: [Index formulae for singular lines of polarization](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1464-4258/6/7/003)), here it gives a calculation for the major and minor axis for ellipse polarizations:

$$\textbf{A}+i \textbf{B}=\frac{ \sqrt(\textbf{E}^* \cdot \textbf{E}^*)}{\left| \sqrt(\textbf{E}\cdot \textbf{E})\right|} \textbf{E}$$

But why does it not use the following way to express it: **A**+ i **B** =(conj(E)/abs(E))*E ?
$$\textbf{A}+i \textbf{B}=\frac{ \textbf{E}^*}{\left| \textbf{E} \right|} \textbf{E}$$

It seems better and simpler to write it in this way. So, why does the paper define it in such a complicated way?

Comment: Welcome to SE. Please avoid using screenshots. This site provides Mathjax to typeset equations (a syntaxe very close to LaTeX). Thank you.

Comment: I am sorry, but cannot find the Mathjax. I have a try later

Comment: You can have a look [at this post on the math site](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?rq=1). Quick summary: just type equations in your text, using LaTeX syntax.

Comment: Oh, I got it. Thanks very much, and you can see the new version. You can ignore the screenshots, and read the text directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because $E$ is a vector, and writing $\sqrt(E.E)$ is the common way to express the (euclidian) norm of a vector in physics litterature. You could write $||E||$ instead, but then you would need to precise which norm you use (there are several other commonly used norms in mathematics).

Finally, while the alternative you propose $\frac{E^*}{|E|}E$ could be used (I have seen many teacher counfound vector and their norm in their notation), I would advise against it because it is not simpler. You give the same symbol the meaning of a norm in the fraction part of the formula, and the meaning of a vector just next to it. You should at the very least put the vector in bold, or add an arrow above it (but then you need to do that in your whole book/article). Unfortunately, for a lot of reader, distinguishing between bold and normal character is not easy, and writing a lot of arrows is unpractical. So using $E$ only as a vector (and never as the norm of the vector) is IMHO the simplest solution to not counfound vectors with their norm.